# js date separator gives different answers when using getDate()

Tags: javascript, date

In the code below, why do we get different answers with getDate()

```js
 temp = new Date("2022-05-15")
 temp1 = new Date('2022/05/15')

console.log(temp.getDate())
console.log(temp1.getDate())
```

Comment: Browsers (and JavaScript environments in general) are allowed to be "picky" about date formats they recognize.

Comment: Print the whole date, you'll see that they have different times, because one is UTC, the other is in the local timezone.

Comment: And when the UTC date is converted to the local timezone, the day changes.

Comment: how do you convert?

Comment: Don't use the built-in date parser. Use a library like `moment.js` that gives you more control.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMAScript standard defines certain date/time strings that are parsed in a standard way: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format

Any other values the client chooses to accept may be implementation specific. Mozilla documents some common behaviors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#fall-back_to_implementation-specific_date_formats

If you specifically intend to support yyyy/mm/dd in a cross-client compatible way, you may want to parse it yourself and supply the values to the `new Date(year, month, day)` (noting that month is 0-indexed "off by one")

```
const [yyyy,mm,dd] = '2022/05/15'.split(/\D/);
new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd)
```

or simply `new Date('2022/05/15'.replace(/\//g, '-'))`

Comment: The first part can be `let [y, m, d] = '2022/05/15'.split(/\D/)`. The use of *parseInt* is unnecessary. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In different parts of the world, date is described in different ways.

1. Date according to the ISO is, **yyyy-mm-dd**
2. Date according to some countries like USA is, **mm/dd/yyyy**
3. Date according to most other countries is, **dd/mm/yyyy**

Most Javascript implementations support the first two formats. Its said that some browser implementations of javascript try to guess if the third format is used and adapt.

To be on the safer side, go with the ISO format (**yyyy-mm-dd**). Or if you have trouble remembering which separator is used by ISO, you can skip the string and enter the date elements as comma separated values.

```js
temp = new Date(2022, 4, 15);
// month is indexed from 0, so Jan will be 0, feb will be 1 and so on.
console.log(temp.getDate());
```

This page has info on which format works and which doesn't (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp).

Comment: The difference is that YYYY-MM-DD is parsed as UTC (per ECMA-262), whereas parsing of YYYY/MM/DD is implementation dependent and may be parsed as UTC, local or invalid. `new Date(2022, 5, 15)` creates a date for 15 June, not 15 May.